# What triggers a Skull of Fate roll?

Tags: dark-quest

While wandering the first level of the dungeon in *Dark Quest* it would occasionally make me roll the Skull if Fate. These had negative consequences on all but one roll. Are the triggers for these rolls completely random (such as a x% chance per turn) or was it based on some actions I took or squares I stepped on?